# Почему длина строки не равна объявленной?

Tags: c++, строки

```
char * s3 = new char[42];
l3 = strlen(s3);
```

Я объявил строку длиной 42 символа но l3 равна 47
Что пошло не так?

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` ищет первый символ равный `0`. Количество символов до него - это результат функции `strlen`. Оператор `new` выделяет память и никак её не инициализирует. Память заполнена случайными данными. Вам повезло, что нулевой байт оказался так близко. Иначе вы могли получить ошибку `segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, какой компилятор и где объявлено. Попробуй вот так:

```
char * s3 = new char[42]{0};
int l3 = strlen(s3);
```

Длина должна быть равна нулю.

Comment: компилятор - визуал студио
Да длинна выходит нулевой

Comment: Положа лапу на сердце - не помню. Надо смотреть Стандарт. В одних случаях будет явная инициализация нулем, в других будет мусор (отсутствие инициализации). Сорри, не помню. Для себя взял за правило - инициализировать все явно. Возможно это и паранойя, но так проще, лично мне.

Answer (score 1):

> Я обьявил строку длинной 42 символа но l3 равна 47 Что пошло не так?

Нет, вы нигде не объявляли строку длиной 42 символа. В этом фрагменте кода

```
char * s3 = new char[42];
l3 = strlen(s3);
```

вы объявили одну переменную: переменную `s3`, имеющую тип указателя `char *`. В этом фрагменте кода вообще нигде не используется строка.

Строка - это последовательность символов, ограниченная завершающем нулем, то есть символом `'\0'`.

Указатель `s3` инициализирован адресом первого байта динамически выделенной памяти размером в 42 байта. Однако сама динамически выделенная память никак не инициализирована, поэтому к ней бессмысленно применять функцию `strlen`.

Вы могли бы инициализировать выделенную память нулями, например, следующим образом

```
char * s3 = new char[42]();
```

и тогда бы эта память в самом своем начале содержала бы пустую строку, то есть строку, которая состоит из одного символа `'\0'`.

В этом случае результат применения функции `strlen` будет равен 0.

Из описания функции `strlen`  в стандарте C

> The strlen function returns the number of characters that precede the
>   terminating null character.

Когда вы динамически выделяете память, то вам нужно самому хранить размер выделенной памяти в некоторой переменной. Например,

```
int n = 42;
char *str = new char[n];
```

Если бы вы вместо динамически выделенного символьного массива и объявления соответствующего указателя, объявили массив, например, таким образом

```
char str[42];
```

то оператор `sizeof( str )` вернул бы вам значение 42. Этот оператор возвращает размер памяти, занимаемой массивом, но тем, не менее, он не пригоден для определении длины строки, которая может храниться в этом массиве.

Например,

```
char str[42] = "Hello";

std::cout << sizeof( str ) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::strlen( str ) << std::endl;
```

Первое из этих предложений выведет `42`, в то время как второе предложение - `5`.

Оператор `sizeof` бессмысленно применять к указателю на выделенную динамически память, как, например,

```
char *str = new char[42];
size_t n = sizeof( str );
```

потому что он вернет не размер выделенной динамической памяти, а размер самого указателя, которой в зависимости от используемой системы может быть равным, например, 4 или 8.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48868/discussion-on-answer-by-vlad-from-moscow------).